# Run test with only one data row, mstest

Tags: c#, tfs, mstest

Good day. I have c#, mstest and data for tests in TFS.
Some of tests contain parameters. How should I update my code to run test only with one data row?

```
[TestMethod, Priority(1), TestCategory("SomeCategory")]
[DataSource(DATA_SOURCE, TFS_URL, "TestCaseNumber", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void MyTest()
    {...}
```

Just for example, I want to start test only with parameters from 10th row except waiting for previous 9 runs.

It will be great to degub.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no out-of-the-box way to do this.  Your best bet is to move the specific data row to the top of the table so it is run first then you can abort the test run when you are done debugging.  I don't believe Test Manager supports reording rows so you will have to manually swap all the fields in the first and the specific row you need.